# How to create a SQL statement to count value from rows

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to build a SQL that will return the total amount of file for all the events.

DB:

```
id | name    | filename1 | filename2
1    event1    1.jpg       2.jpg
2    event2    1.jpg       Null
```

If you look at this scenario it should return "You have 3 files" but I have no idea how to make the SQL.

I'm using mySQL.

Thanks

Comment: Why do you have two columns for filenames?

Comment: You should save filenames in one column and set some flag for each row indicating what filename you saved in this row

Comment: I wish I could change the DB but they wont

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can *unpivot* or use `UNION ALL` on the data in the `filename1` and `filename2` fields and then get a total count. The `UNION ALL` takes the data from the multiple columns and converts it into multiple rows:

```
select count(files) Total
from
(
    select name, filename1 as files
    from yourtable
    union all
    select name, filename2
    from yourtable
) src
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c16d6/1)

Comment: Love this approach...Thanks a lot.

Comment: Curious why you don't have to also create an alias for filename2 (filename2 as files)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22843/discussion-between-yannick-and-bluefeet)

Answer (score 1):

Your table is not normalized and this is making your life difficult.  When you have a one to many relationship like event:files, you need 2 tables, one for events and one for files belonging to events.  Like this:

### events

```
event_id int unsigned not null auto_increment
event_name varchar(45)
....
```

### eventfiles

```
file_id int unsigned not null auto_increment
event_id int unsigned not null,
file_name varchar(45)
....
```

To get the total number of files, just do:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM eventfiles;
```

If you want to get the number of files per event, do this:

```
SELECT e.event_name, COUNT(f.file_id)
FROM events e LEFT JOIN eventfiles f ON e.event_id=f.event_id
GROUP BY e.event_name;
```

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify what is in the column when there is no filename there, I assume that it is NULL then (as it should be).

I'm uncertain about the performance - but this should work in that case:

```
SELECT 
SUM(CASE WHEN filename1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN filename2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) img_cnt
FROM event_table;
```

You could also get the count for individual events by event ID too:

```
SELECT event_id
SUM(CASE WHEN filename1 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
CASE WHEN filename2 IS NOT NULL THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) img_cnt
FROM event_table
GROUP BY event_id
```

Also, it is very true that this DB structure is not nice. It should be normalized, as dnagirl suggested!